# How python finds the support vectors in the kernelized SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, svm

When the classes are overlapped, the kernel SVM moves the data to a higher dimensionality to find an optimal separation between classes. If SVM finds the separate hyperplane in the transformed data, this means it finds the support vectors in the transformed data. My question is, how Python gives me the support vectors in the original data?  is there a dekernalized process? How exactly this done, I can't find an answer from the Python documentation.

Update: this is an example from the following website 
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.07-support-vector-machines.html

```
clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1E6)
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.support_vectors_[:, 0], clf.support_vectors_[:, 1]
```

Comment: it's not a dekernelization. The kernels work only becuase the cross product in the original data space is equivalent to the cross product in the kernel space. As a result, the original data points are returned without having to go through a "dekernalization process". I'm not surprised that this is not in the the sklearn documentation - you'd have better luck finding this in a textbook that discusses SVMs. I use [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Machine-Learning-Science-Algorithms-Sense/dp/1107422221/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1)

Comment: This is the problem! if for example, the dot product is 16, how I know it comes from 4 * 4 or 2 * 8?

Comment: You'll know it by whether `(4, 4)` or `(2, 8)` are returned to you as the support vectors

Comment: This is my question! how Python figure it out? this is a serious issue in SVM.

Comment: The support vectors are discovered by identifying the closest vectors to the separating plane. This is done with basic calculus. The overall process of discovering all support vectors is done through a process called quadratic programming (or at least, that's how it was done 9 years ago - but that's just an implementation detail)

Comment: Diffenatily it is not a basic calculus. It is a dual optimization problem solved by Lagrange multiplier and it is computationally expensive to solve either by QP or SMO. However, thanks for your comments but they don't help me. Please read the question. This issue is serious and it is mentioned by many high-quality research papers, and I am trying to mention it in my research. Thanks again